# Tufte-style book with ConTeXt

Tags: context, rstudio, rmarkdown, tufte-book

Is there any tufte-style formatting in ConTeXt as a module? I have seen references to `\usemodule[tufte]` in some documents but I can't find how to use this module in ConTeXt garden site. I'm using quarto to generate TeX output from markdown file, using `context` as engine, and I compile .text with `context` in Windows.

Comment: You can get most(all?) of it with some rather simple setups. I have not seen them collected anywhere, but is there something in particular that you cannot achieve.

Comment: I am a new user of ConTeXt, I have used LaTeX for some time, getting the formatting options was easy, and when in doubt, you can get advice from many sources. I just can't get any about how to format in ConTeXt. I guess you have to craft it all step by step... Having a template or basic document with example would be of significant help, same as you can find on the web for LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I found is https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Sidenotes_style with a github page https://github.com/andythomas/TeX-sidenotes. I tried to use it and got confused because of my ignorance of ConTeXt.

I'm learning ConTeXt and looking for tufte-style formatting too. I ask questions here and get helpful answers, for example: [ConTeXt: Need help understanding \setupbackgrounds when layer is postponed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667374/context-need-help-understanding-setupbackgrounds-when-layer-is-postponed/667429#667429).  In my layout, the margin column is on the left of a page.

Comment: Thanks for help, Stanley. The code in GitHub is 10 years old! I find quite surprising there's nothing newer... I will try it anyway. [There is a ConTeXt guide](https://github.com/contextgarden/not-so-short-introduction-to-context) I'm sure you know, it's the only clear guide I have found.

Comment: Yes, and there are some guides that are not clear, to me now.