# ConTeXt: How can I have body text beside a bottom float caption in the margin?

Tags: floats, context, tufte

I changed mickep's answer at [ConTeXt: Need help understanding \setupbackgrounds when layer is postponed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667374/context-need-help-understanding-setupbackgrounds-when-layer-is-postponed) to have full-width images across the margin + main text. I fiddled and got the caption to appear above the image as I wanted. This had 2 problems:

1 - On page 1, the body text only comes down as far as the top of the caption in the margin. I would like it to come down to just above the cow.

2 - When ConTeXt pushes the float to the next page, the image is at the top of the page, with the caption above. In this situation, I would like the caption to be below the image.

If it's simple and easy to fix these problems, I'd like to know. Otherwise I'm exploring other ways to achieve what I want.

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]

\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\definefloat[bottomfigure][figure][
    default=bottom,
    location=innermargin, % moves image left 
]
\setupcaption[bottomfigure][
    location=top,
    width=40mm,
    align={flushleft},
] 
\starttext 
Some text at the start

\startplacebottomfigure[title={The Futch cow looks to the left to get the margin right.}]
\externalfigure[cow][width=150mm]
\stopplacebottomfigure

\startplacebottomfigure[title={The French parlex voux.}]
\externalfigure[hacker][width=150mm]
\stopplacebottomfigure

\dorecurse{1}{\samplefile{tufte}\par}
\stoptext
```

[image: Mad cow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We can cheat and put the caption into a layer.
2. If there is not enough space you (currently) need to postpone, otherwise it seems that the image is placed at the top of the next page. An alternative is to cheat with the corner and location of the layer, but I think you are in a manual state then.

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]

\setupalign[height]

\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\definefloat[bottomfigure][figure][
    default={bottom,none},
    location=innermargin,
]

\setupcaption[figure][
    style=small,
] 

\defineframed[captionframed][
    align=flushleft,
    width=40mm,
    offset=overlay,
    boffset=\lineheight,
    frame=no,
]

\definelayer[Stanley]

\setuplayer[Stanley][
    corner=lefttop,
    location={right,top},
]

\startsetups Stanley
\setlayer[Stanley]{\getbuffer[Stanley]}
\stopsetups

\defineexternalfigure[Stanley][externalfigure][
    setups=Stanley,
    background=Stanley,
]

\starttext 

\startbuffer[Stanley]
\captionframed{\placefloatcaption[figure][title={This is the caption of the cow picture, and as we know the cow says meow meow!}]}
\stopbuffer

\startplacebottomfigure
\externalfigure[cow][Stanley][width=150mm]
\stopplacebottomfigure

\dorecurse{3}{{\darkblue\samplefile{knuth}}\par}

\startbuffer[Stanley]
\captionframed{\placefloatcaption[figure][title={This is the caption of the hacker picture, and as the hacker is hacking, we hear a \quotation{hack hack}!}]}
\stopbuffer

\startpostponing[+1]
\startplacebottomfigure
\externalfigure[hacker][Stanley][width=150mm]
\stopplacebottomfigure
\stoppostponing

\dorecurse{8}{\samplefile{knuth}\par}


\stoptext
```

[image: pictures with non-interfering captions]

In the example I marked the spot where we try to insert the hacker by changing color. As you see, there is not sufficient space left.

Comment: That's great. I'll look in the wiki to understand what's happening. And, as usual you teach me how to write ConTeXt documents better.

Comment: Please help me understand your answer. In \defineexternalfigure … what does [background=Stanley] do? I assume it at least does \setupbackgrounds to activate the layer? Does [setups=Stanley] mean that Stanley is executed when I create an externalfigure? The documentation says that setups are a variant on macros. Do they set-up/initialise things as the name implies?

Comment: The `background=Stanley` applies the Stanley layer _to the image (frame)_. The setups is used in order to be able to use the same layer several times like this (see [this section](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers#Use_dynamic_content)). I do not know how setups work internaly.

Comment: Aaaah. When I  read about layers, I always skipped over that section because it seemed daunting. Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: There is no need to use setups here because we call \externalfigure twice in different places in the code. And can set up the required layer before each call. I deleted all references to setups and doing this (in 2 places) worked: `\startplacebottomfigure`, `\setlayer[Stanley]{\getbuffer[Stanley]}`, `\externalfigure[cow][Stanley][width=150mm]`, `\stopplacebottomfigure`. The example at https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers#Use_dynamic_content is different because without setups there is no place to set up the different layer for each page.

Comment: Thanks for reporting! I thought I tried without setups first, but I must have done something else wrong then.