# ConTeXt: How to have a float across the top with some text below in left margin?

Tags: floats, context, layers

I used mikep's technique from [ConTeXt: How can I have body text beside a bottom float caption in the margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667467/context-how-can-i-have-body-text-beside-a-bottom-float-caption-in-the-margin) but now I want the floating image at the top, with the text in the left margin below. The layer StanleyL seems to be small and at the top of the left margin. Therefore I can't move the margin text to below the image by changing the layer's corner or location. See screenshot and MEW1.

Question 1 - Can I move the layer StanleyL to below the image ?

If not, I could use the dimensions of the image to calculate where the top of the text has to be. Because the image gets scaled when it is placed, I need to calculate \fullwidth x \figureheight / \figurewidth. I tried using dimexprs and numexprs but they didn't work. I tried some lua, which worked when I fed it integer numbers, byt failed when I fed it numbers like \figurewidth. MWE2.

Question 2 - How can I calculate the height of the image when it is placed ?

[image: cow caption]
MWE1:

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]
\setupalign[height]
\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\newdimen\fullwidth     % margin + main text
\fullwidth= \dimexpr(\leftmarginwidth+\leftmargindistance + \makeupwidth)

\setupexternalfigures[location=default]
\definefloat[bottomfigure][figure][
    default={top,none},
    location=innermargin,
]
\setupcaption[figure][style=small,] 
\defineframed[captionframed]
    [align={flushleft}, width=40mm, offset=overlay, boffset=\lineheight, frame=on, ]

\definelayer[StanleyL]
\setuplayer[StanleyL][corner=lefttop,location={right,top},]

\defineexternalfigure[StanleyF][externalfigure][background=StanleyL,]

\starttext 

\startplacebottomfigure
\setlayer[StanleyL]{\captionframed{\placefloatcaption[figure][title={This is the caption of the cow picture}]}}
\externalfigure[cow][StanleyF][width=\fullwidth]
\stopplacebottomfigure

\dorecurse{3}{{\darkblue\samplefile{knuth}}\par}
\stoptext
```

MWE2:

```
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\def\myheight#1#2#3%
    {\ctxlua{context(#1 * #2 / #3)}}

\starttext

\getfiguredimensions[cow]
\figureheight---\figurewidth---\the\textwidth

% this works, but not if I pass it \figurewidth or context.figurewidth
\myheight {3}{8}{4} 
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this, so I could use the same mechanism for top and bottom floats. There are a couple of problems if ConTeXt decides to push the float to a later page:

1 - The caption is on the wrong page. You might be able to fix this with a setup, as mikep describes here [ConTeXt: How can I have body text beside a bottom float caption in the margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667467/context-how-can-i-have-body-text-beside-a-bottom-float-caption-in-the-margin)

2 - A bottom float might become a top float. The caption is in the wrong place in the margin!

[image]

```
\showframe 
\setupexternalfigures[location=default] % get the cow
\setupalign[height] % need so floats at bottom reach the bottom !

\definepapersize[mypage][height=260mm, width=185mm]
\setuppapersize[mypage] 

\setuplayout
    [backspace=58mm, width=106mm, leftmargin=32mm, leftmargindistance=5mm,
    topspace=20mm, height=220mm, footer=5mm, footerdistance=5mm,header=0mm]

\newdimen\fullwidth     % margin + main text
\fullwidth= \dimexpr(\leftmargintotal + \makeupwidth)

% the layer
\definelayer[mylayer][width=\fullwidth, height=\textheight] 
\setupbackgrounds[text] [leftmargin]
    [background=mylayer,state=repeat,]% seems redundant

\newdimen\figurecaptiongap      \figurecaptiongap= 3mm  % from figure to caption

\defineframedtext[margincaption][frame=on, location=top, offset=0mm, align={flushleft}, style={\ss\switchtobodyfont[9pt]}, width=\leftmarginwidth]  

\defineexternalfigure [fullwidthfigure][width=\fullwidth]
\getfiguredimensions    % enable \figureheight, set after each \externalfigure

% the float figure
\definefloat[fullwidthfloat][figure]
    [location=leftmargin,]

% 1 = must be top or bottom, 2 = image,  3 = text
\define[3]\macfloatfullwidth
{
\startplacefloat [fullwidthfloat][location={#1,none}]% must do float before caption
    \externalfigure[#2][fullwidthfigure]
\stopplacefloat

\setlayer[mylayer]
    [preset=left#1, voffset=\figureheight + \figurecaptiongap]
    {\margincaption[]{#3} }  
}

\starttext
\dorecurse{1}{\input tufte}
\macfloatfullwidth {top}{cow}{This is  a cow}
\dorecurse{2}{\input tufte}
\macfloatfullwidth {bottom}{hacker}{These are hackers busy hacking}
\dorecurse{4}{\input tufte}
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought that answer had an update, but anyways. Maybe this is a starting point? (I don't see how to get rid of/configure the space below the cow.)

Regarding Question 2 I do not know/understand what you want to do.

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]

\setupalign[height]
\setuplayout
  [backspace=80mm,
   width=100mm,
   topspace=50mm,
   header=0mm,
   footer=0mm,
   height=200mm,
   margindistance=10mm,
   leftmargin=40mm]


\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setupcaptions
  [width=\leftmarginwidth,
   align={width,hanging},
   style={\tfx\setupinterlinespace}]

\definefloat
  [top]
  [figure]
  [default={top},
   location=leftmargin]

\setupcaption
  [top]
  [location={bottom,overlay}]

\defineexternalfigure
  [full]
  [width=\dimexpr\leftmargintotal+\textwidth\relax]


\starttext
\dorecurse{3}{\samplefile{douglas}\par}

\startplacefloat
  [top]
  [title={\samplefile{ward}\par}]
\externalfigure[cow][full]
\stopplacefloat

\dorecurse{3}{\samplefile{knuth}\par}
\stoptext
```

[image: cow with caption below]

Comment: That answer was an update to an earlier question. I'll post my question about calculating in a separate post.

Comment: I just found something I didn't expect. My question 2 was to calculate image heights. I expected that \getfiguredimensions would give the natural dimensions of the image, the same as what a photo editing app would give. But, if I first call \getfiguredimensions (with no square brackets after) once, then any time I place any image, \figureheight gets updated to the actual height of that image in my document. I have my answer without needing to do any calculations.